# Why's my table showing data under one column only?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Anyone know why my table's only returning all data only to column `A`?  Both `{oppDescData()}` and `contestEntriesData()` are all coming up under column `A`.

I've tried removing the `<tr></tr>`s from both methods to only return `<td></td>` but to no avail.

https://pastebin.com/xwHjRNWE

Comment: Post code here and not in links, please. Eventually the provided link will expire, leaving a post with no context for users with a similar problem. Additionally, by linking the code, you are telling people to jump through some arbitrary hoops just so they can help.

Answer (score 1):

Each method is returning a series of rows with one column. You need to combine their outputs so that they are output side-by-side instead of independently, so you most likely need to merge your two functions.

Answer (score 0):

You render the headings into 2 different cells, while the data is rendered into only 1 cell but in separate rows.

You should combine your `oppDescData` and `contestEntriesData` so it will be rendered within 1 row

```
<tr>
  <td>
    {oppDesc}
  </td>
  <td>
    {entries}
  </td>
</tr>
```